# SQL Server Convert multiple Rows(visit dates) to Column using pivot

Tags: dynamic-pivot

I need help with converting multiple date of visits into columns using SQL server. I know this can be done in pivot.  I have tried but can't get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks much!
I have sample data in columns; ID,DOB, visitDate and NumberOfVisits.
[image]

and would like to have outputs look like this.
[image]

Comment: Recommendation: replace images with actual formatted code or text.